# How to capture control key event in mac (in as3/flash)?

Tags: windows, macos, actionscript-3, flash

I am developing an application in flash as3.I need to capture CONTROL_KEY Event.
**What i did works fine in most of the browsers on Windows but when using MacOS, the CONTROL_KEY event gets replaced with the COMMAND key on MAC.**

**How can I make my application capture only control key on both the platforms?  This is the code i have written for capturing the keydown and keyup events.**

```
public function classConstructor()
{ 
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyboardKeyDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyboardKeyUp);
}

 private function keyboardKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case 17:
            if(isCtrlKeyDown==false){
                isCtrlKeyDown=true;
                isBombActive=true;
                trace("Ctrl and Mouse Clicked Together");
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    private function keyboardKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {

            case 17:
            if(isCtrlKeyDown){
                isCtrlKeyDown=false;
                isBombActive=false;
                trace("Ctrl Released Together");
            }

            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the commandKey propriety on the KeyboardEvent. See here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html